# Updating an app in Android under the system directory

Tags: android, installation, system, apk

I have a product using Android 2.3, and my app is put into /system/app/.

Now when my app find new version, my app try to download the .apk(updated version) file to /system/app/ , but  failed. I couldn't create file in /system/app/.

So, how could I update my app locate in /system/app?
(I have all source code of **Android+Linux kernel+uboot** of my product.)

piece of code:

```
case WdtMessage.UPDATE:
    Log.i(TAG,     "======================update");
    FileOutputStream out = null;                        
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream("/system/app/dddddddd.apk");
        out.write((updateFileBuffer));
    }catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
        Log.i(TAG, "======================err"+e.toString());
}

create file Permission denied!
```

Comment: But I want to do this automatically, because nobody could touch the device, it is running on wild alone.

Answer (score -1):

Google's new policy doesn't allow apps in the Play Store that try to update themselves. Updates must be passed through the Play Store.

If you're not looking to put your app up in the store, as far as I know, you wont be able to overwrite the APK (without root access).

PS : Facebook recently did something similar with their application, if you really need this, try researching how they did it.

EDIT:

For your requirements, you will need root access. So the device you're developing on needs to be rooted. With that in mind , you could use [RootTools](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/) to access the /system/app/ directory.

Comment: But the device is specified by our company, it is special used device.  The os version is 2.3.1. google play  is deleted by us, because we will only be allow to run my app on start.

Comment: And we want to auto update my app installed on /system/app/ in background. Because the device is run automatic in the wild.

Comment: I have the Android kernal+Linux code for my device. If so, When I want to update my app under /system/app,